# How to know in what tag my object is currently on?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

Lets say we make a soup object:

```
html = '''<html><head>HEAD!</head><body>BODY!</body></html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I need a check to tell me if the object 'soup' IS currently in the < html> tag (the root).
Something like:

```
is_head_tag(soup)
```

returning True/False.

Is it possible? I scrolled the documentation some times but I found nothing.

THank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer!

the attribute .name does exactly this!
We could define the is_head_tag() function like below:

```
def is_head_tag(soup):
    if soup.name == 'head':
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: I don't see how that works with your example, also never use is for comparing strings use `==` also `bool(soup.head)` might be closer to what you want

Comment: I wanted to check if the object's root tag is 'html' (or anything). Can you please explain why the == instead of 'is'?

Comment: try `a = "$foo" b = "$foo" a is b`

Comment: Tried. Researching the reasons right now!
You opened my eyes to something new! Thanks a lot

Comment: no worries, `is` is used to check that two objects are in fact the same object

Comment: Oh, like the == and equals() difference in Java.